# Can I detect a QWERTY / AZERTY keyboard with Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, keyboard

I want to set some shortcuts according to the keyboard type, so that it is always a line of keys (`Q-W-E` or `A-Z-E`). That would require to hardcode the shortcuts depending on the keyboard type I know.

Is it possible to retrieve this information with Qt ?

Comment: slightly offtopic: I am used to switch between different keyboard layouts and I would find it confusing if depending on the layout the shortcuts are different. Also it would make it difficult for people using different layouts to talk about the program. "I used the XY shortcut" - "The what? In my version there is no such shortcut"

Comment: @tobi303 Some times you may want to enforce the layout of some key combinations. For instance for games where on QWERTY keyboards, the keys W, S, A and D are used as Up, Down, Left, Right. For AZERTY keyboards you want to keep the layout and remap to Z, S, Q and D.

Comment: @BenjaminT I would call that "shortcut", though I completely get your point. I just think that in general its not nice to replace eg ctrl+z with ctrl+y just to have the key at the same place on the keyboard, whether OPs case is an exception I dont know

Comment: @tobi303 I agree with you, it really depends on the use of your application. I am working for an application where the user will not play with the system or the keyboard at all so it makes sense to force this in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get the Keyboard QLocale with http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qinputmethod.html#locale-prop

Something like

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);
qDebug() << a.inputMethod()->locale();
```

Or

```
qDebug() << QLocale::system();
```

Give me QLocale(French, Latin, France) and QLocale(French, Default, France)

Comment: So I should then compare the locale to *language+country*s that use QWERTY ? I guess it would work but it is quite hard to maintain if you want to deploy in many countries

Comment: Edit: the list of countries using AZERTY is basically limited to France and few custom layouts so I could check this and consider the rest as QWERTY. Thx !

Comment: I never had to do something like that, I just give just some hint

Comment: I was able to detect my azerty keyboard like this `bool isAzerty = qApp->inputMethod()->locale().language() == QLocale::French;`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

```
#include <QLocale>

int main() {

  QLocale locale;

  if (locale.language() == QLocale::Language::French) {
    // Do something
  } else {
    // Do something else
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Of course it works with every language.